# Why am I getting 100% accuracy in XGBoostClassifier?

Tags: machine-learning, python, accuracy, boosting

So I am doing some predictive analytics on banking information and the target variable is whether or not a member has a checking. I printed the correlations between each variable to the *HasChecking* variable, and then removed collinear variables to reduce the impact on my model (this includes removing any *Checking* related variables).

This is a list of my chosen features, and the code below is how I got to them.

```
'CD_Balance', 'Vehicle_Balance', 'HasCreditCard', 'HasCD',
'CreditCard_CurrentMonthTransAmt', 'FICO', 'NearestBranchDistance',
'Saving_Balance', 'HasVehicle', 'Service_SavingNSF/CourtesyTransCnt',
'HouseholdIncomeDesc', 'CreditCard_CurrentMonthTransCnt', 'HasSaving',
'Vehicle_CurrentMonthTransCnt', 'CD_Count',
'Saving_CurrentMonthTransCnt', 'TotalLoanDelinquents',
'CreditCard_Balance'
```

**Collinearity Pruning**

```
# Select target variable
targetVariable = "HasChecking"

# Service_SavingNSF/CourtesyTransCnt leads to a 100% accuracy rate and that is not possible
dropColumns = [targetVariable, "MemberMPI", "Tenure"]#, "Service_SavingNSF/CourtesyTransCnt"]

# Grab the correlations and print them for HasChecking
dfCorr = df.corr()
dfCorr.sort_values([targetVariable], ascending=False, inplace=True)
print(dfCorr[targetVariable])

dfCorrelationTable = dfCorr.HasChecking.to_frame()
dfCorrelationTable = dfCorrelationTable.reset_index()
dfCorrelationTable.columns = ["ColumnName", "Correlation"]

collinearThreshold = .90

# Get only features that have a magnitude .15 correlation or higher)
dfCorrelationTable = [col for col in ','.join(
    dfCorrelationTable[
        (abs(dfCorrelationTable["Correlation"]) > .10) & (dfCorrelationTable["Correlation"] <= collinearThreshold)].ColumnName).split(",") 
        if ("Checking" not in col or col == targetVariable)]

# Get rid of collinear values. They add redundancy and overfit the model.
filterCollinear = set()
for col in dfCorrelationTable:
    for otherCol in dfCorrelationTable:
        if otherCol == col:
            continue
        dfCorr.sort_values([col], ascending=False, inplace=True)
        if (dfCorr[col][otherCol] > collinearThreshold):
            lowerCol = col if abs(dfCorr[targetVariable][col]) < abs(dfCorr[targetVariable][otherCol]) else otherCol
            filterCollinear.add(lowerCol)
print("These are the collinear items", filterCollinear)

dfCorrelationTable = set(dfCorrelationTable) - filterCollinear
cols = list(dfCorrelationTable)
cols.append("MemberMPI")
cols.append(targetVariable)

dfInputData = df[cols]
```

Now, my model runs decently without the input feature *Service_SavingNSF/CourtesyTransCnt*.

[image]

But when I add in *Service_SavingNSF/CourtesyTransCnt*, the accuracy is impossibly high. What are some issues I may have missed? I also left my training/testing code down below as well. My first thought is multicollinearity, but I thought ML algorithms aren't too affected by that.

[image]

[image]

**Resample and Training**

```
from sklearn.utils import resample
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report 

# Grab which boolean has more samples so we can do resampling
majorityBoolean = 0 if len(dfInputData.loc[df[targetVariable] == 0]) >= len(dfInputData.loc[df[targetVariable] == 1]) else 1
df_majority = dfInputData.loc[dfInputData[targetVariable] == majorityBoolean]
df_minority = dfInputData.loc[dfInputData[targetVariable] != majorityBoolean]

# Resample the majority down to minority
df_majority_downsampled = resample(df_majority, replace=False, 
                                   n_samples=len(df_minority), 
                                   random_state=45)
df_downsampled = pd.concat([df_majority_downsampled, df_minority])

#filteringDf = dfInputData[np.logical_not(dfInputData.MemberMPI.isin(df_downsampled.MemberMPI))]

df_downsampled = pd.concat([df_majority.iloc[0:int(len(df_majority)*.25),:], df_minority.iloc[0:int(len(df_majority)*.25),:]])
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df_downsampled.drop(dropColumns, axis=1).as_matrix(), df_downsampled[targetVariable], test_size=0.20)
X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val   = train_test_split(X_train, y_train, test_size=0.20)
xgb = XGBClassifier(learning_rate=0.0732595425042909, max_depth=8, n_estimators=181, subsample=0.1554808063285612)
xgb = xgb.fit(X_train, y_train)

pscore = xgb.predict_proba(X_val)[:,1]
preds = xgb.predict(X_val)
print(classification_report(y_val, preds))
print("ROC AUC Score Validation = " + str(roc_auc_score(y_val, pscore)))
print("Validation Accuracy = " + str(xgb.score(X_val, y_val)))

print()

preds = xgb.predict(X_test)
pscore = xgb.predict_proba(X_test)[:,1]
print(classification_report(y_test, preds))
print("ROC AUC Score Test = " + str(roc_auc_score(y_test, pscore)))
print("Test Accuracy = " + str(xgb.score(X_test, y_test)))
```

Comment: Any ideas? If you need more information I can provide it.

Comment: Are you sure you aren't leaking information on the outcome?  For instance, a client can't default on a loan if they haven't applied for one.  Can you be confident something similar isn't happening?

Comment: You probably are dealing with leakage: one of your input features is actually a direct proxy for your target variable.

Comment: Could the culprit be the variable Service_SavingNSF/CourtesyTransCnt, which immediately leads to 100% accuracy once I add it in? Or is it just a byproduct of some other possible feature