# Why my XGBoostClassifier model results in perfect accuracy despite dropping corelated features?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, boosting, accuracy

I am trying to do a binary classification on ticket canceling data from kaggle.

I know this question has been asked before. For example [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/442068/why-am-i-getting-100-accuracy-in-xgboostclassifier) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64582234/xgbclassifier-gives-100-accuracy-on-test-data)

Summary of what I learned in those references:

1. this can happen if data is unbalanced
2. data leakage: one of the input features is actually a direct proxy for the target variable.

My data is unbalanced but not extremely unbalanced. Since this is binary classification:

```
y.sum()/len(y) = 0.151
```

Thus I have about 15% in one category. This is high but not exterme. For data leakage, I looked at the correlation matrix which is as follows:
[image]

The feature importance is [image]

The target variable is "Cancel". None of the variables have extremely high correlation. The model is

```
   model = XGBClassifier(objective='multi:softmax', num_class=3)
```

Yet my classification report is perfect:

```
          precision    recall  f1-score   support

       0       1.00      1.00      1.00     21455
       1       1.00      1.00      1.00      3781

accuracy                            1.00     25236
macro avg       1.00      1.00      1.00     25236
weighted avg    1.00      1.00      1.00     25236
```

How to solve this?

Comment: Is this classification report calculated using a separate test set?

Comment: yes, for a test_train split